# ViewModelProviders java.lang.RuntimeException trying to instantiate class which inherit AndroidViewModel

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I am creating an app using architecture components.

Debug build runs fine, but when testing the release APK the app crashes with the stack trace seen below.

What is strange is that I have 6 fragments with viewmodels that are set up the same way. 2 of them crash, 4 of them works as intended.

The project is not doing any proguard minifying.

I am using architecture components with the following dependencies:

```
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:${arch}"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:${arch}"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:${arch}"
```

Version of architecture components is '1.0.0-beta2' (arch = '1.0.0-beta2'). If I try version of architecture components is '1.0.0-rc1' (arch = '1.0.0-rc1') I get the same problem.

I instantiate my viewmodel from the fragment like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    otherWorkViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(OtherWorkViewModel.class);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        // Check for arguments to fragment (section object and position in list)
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            OtherWork otherWork = (OtherWork) getArguments().get("otherWork");
            otherWorkViewModel.setOtherWork(otherWork);

            int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
            otherWorkViewModel.setPosition(position);
        } 
    }
}
```

When running the library code to instantiate the viewmodel the app crashes with the following exception:

```
10-20 08:41:03.555 2102-2102/no.example.thisapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: no.example.thisapp, PID: 2102
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class no.example.thisapp.ui.job.pavingreport.OtherWorkViewModel
         at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders$DefaultFactory.create(ViewModelProviders.java:149)
         at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:128)
         at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:96)
         at no.example.thisapp.ui.job.pavingreport.PavingReportDialogOtherWork.onCreate(PavingReportDialogOtherWork.java:57)
         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2339)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1377)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1109)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:996)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:99)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2364)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
      Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.app.Application]
         at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
         at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
         at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders$DefaultFactory.create(ViewModelProviders.java:147)
         at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:128) 
         at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:96) 
         at no.example.thisapp.ui.job.pavingreport.PavingReportDialogOtherWork.onCreate(PavingReportDialogOtherWork.java:57) 
         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2339) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1377) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1109) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:996) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:99) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2364) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700) 
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

**Some more code:**

**The viewmodel:**

```
package no.example.thisapp.ui.job.pavingreport;

import android.app.Application;
import android.databinding.Bindable;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

import no.inforte.android.databinding.BaseObservableViewModel;
import no.inforte.android.validation.Misc;
import no.example.thisapp.R;
import no.example.thisapp.model.pavingreport.OtherWork;


public final class OtherWorkViewModel extends BaseObservableViewModel {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = "OtherWorkViewModel";

    private OtherWork otherWork;
    private int position;

    private NumberFormat numberFormat;

    // Shadow fields for otherArea model object

    private String areaGluedString;
    private String handPavedTonString;
    private String nightWorkTonString;




    OtherWorkViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);

        numberFormat = Misc.getNumberFormat(application);
    }




    // Used when:
    // - accessing values from layout
    // - Returning values to PavingReportListFragment
    public OtherWork getOtherWork() {
        return otherWork;
    }




    // Used when:
    // - Returning values to PavingReportListFragment
    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }




    public void setOtherWork(OtherWork otherWork) {
        this.otherWork = otherWork;
        this.areaGluedString = (otherWork.getAreaGlued() != null && !otherWork.getAreaGlued().isNaN()) ? numberFormat.format(otherWork.getAreaGlued()) : "";
        this.handPavedTonString = (otherWork.getHandPavedTon() != null && !otherWork.getHandPavedTon().isNaN()) ? numberFormat.format(otherWork.getHandPavedTon()) : "";
        this.nightWorkTonString = (otherWork.getHandPavedTon() != null && !otherWork.getHandPavedTon().isNaN()) ? numberFormat.format(otherWork.getHandPavedTon()) : "";
    }




    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }




    public boolean isValidInput() {
        boolean tmpIsValid = true;

        if (!validDrains()) tmpIsValid = false;
        if (!validManHoles()) tmpIsValid = false;
        if (!validOther()) tmpIsValid = false;
        if (!validHandPavedTon()) tmpIsValid = false;
        if (!validNightWorkTon()) tmpIsValid = false;
        if (!validAreaGlued()) tmpIsValid = false;

        return tmpIsValid;
    }


    // Shadow for otherWork.areaGlued (Double)




    @Bindable
    public String getAreaGluedString() {
        return areaGluedString;
    }




    @Bindable
    public String getAreaGluedStringError() {
        return Misc.validateDecimalNumberString(areaGluedString, this.getApplication());
    }




    public void setAreaGluedString(String areaGluedString) {
        this.areaGluedString = areaGluedString;

        if (Misc.isValidDecimalNumber(this.areaGluedString, this.getApplication())) {
            try {
                Number number = numberFormat.parse(this.areaGluedString);
                otherWork.setAreaGlued(number.doubleValue());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.areaGluedString);
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.areaGluedStringError);
    }




    private boolean validAreaGlued() {
        return (otherWork.getAreaGlued() != null && !otherWork.getAreaGlued().isNaN());
    }


    // Shadow for otherWork.handPavedTon (Double)




    @Bindable
    public String getHandPavedTonString() {
        return handPavedTonString;
    }




    @Bindable
    public String getHandPavedTonStringError() {
        return Misc.validateDecimalNumberString(handPavedTonString, this.getApplication());
    }




    public void setHandPavedTonString(String handPavedTonString) {
        this.handPavedTonString = handPavedTonString;

        if (Misc.isValidDecimalNumber(this.handPavedTonString, this.getApplication())) {
            try {
                Number number = numberFormat.parse(this.handPavedTonString);
                otherWork.setHandPavedTon(number.doubleValue());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.handPavedTonString);
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.handPavedTonStringError);
    }




    private boolean validHandPavedTon() {
        return (otherWork.getHandPavedTon() != null && !otherWork.getHandPavedTon().isNaN());
    }


    // Shadow for otherWork.nightWorkTon (Double)




    @Bindable
    public String getNightWorkTonString() {
        return nightWorkTonString;
    }




    @Bindable
    public String getNightWorkTonStringError() {
        return Misc.validateDecimalNumberString(nightWorkTonString, getApplication());
    }




    public void setNightWorkTonString(String nightWorkTonString) {
        this.nightWorkTonString = nightWorkTonString;

        if (Misc.isValidDecimalNumber(this.nightWorkTonString, this.getApplication())) {
            try {
                Number number = numberFormat.parse(this.nightWorkTonString);
                otherWork.setNightWorkTon(number.doubleValue());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.nightWorkTonString);
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.nightWorkTonStringError);
    }




    private boolean validNightWorkTon() {
        return (otherWork.getNightWorkTon() != null && !otherWork.getNightWorkTon().isNaN());
    }




    @Bindable
    public String getDrainsString() {
        if (otherWork.getDrains() != null && otherWork.getDrains() == (int) otherWork.getDrains()) {
            return otherWork.getDrains().toString();
        } else return "";
    }




    private boolean validDrains() {
        return (otherWork.getDrains() != null && otherWork.getDrains() == (int) otherWork.getDrains());
    }




    @Bindable
    public String getDrainsStringError() {
        if (validDrains())
            return null;
        return getApplication().getString(R.string.error_value_required);
    }




    public void setDrainsString(String drainsString) {
        try {
            int drains = Integer.parseInt(drainsString);
            otherWork.setDrains(drains);
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.drainsStringError);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Could not parse integer value...");
        }
    }




    @Bindable
    public String getManHolesString() {
        if (otherWork.getManHoles() != null && otherWork.getManHoles() == (int) otherWork.getManHoles()) {
            return otherWork.getManHoles().toString();
        } else return "";
    }




    private boolean validManHoles() {
        return (otherWork.getManHoles() != null && otherWork.getManHoles() == (int) otherWork.getManHoles());
    }




    @Bindable
    public String getManHolesStringError() {
        if (validManHoles()) return null;
        return getApplication().getString(R.string.error_value_required);
    }




    public void setManHolesString(String manHolesString) {
        try {
            int manHoles = Integer.parseInt(manHolesString);
            otherWork.setManHoles(manHoles);
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.manHolesStringError);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Could not parse integer value...");
        }
    }




    private boolean validOther() {
        return (otherWork.getOther() != null && !otherWork.getOther().isEmpty());
    }




    @Bindable
    public String getOtherError() {
        return (validOther()) ? null : getApplication().getString(R.string.error_value_required);
    }
}
```

**And the BaseObservableViewModel:**

```
package no.inforte.android.databinding;


import android.app.Application;
import android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import android.databinding.Bindable;
import android.databinding.Observable;
import android.databinding.PropertyChangeRegistry;

public class BaseObservableViewModel extends AndroidViewModel implements Observable {
    private transient PropertyChangeRegistry mCallbacks;

    public BaseObservableViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
    }



    // Code below is copied from com.android.databinding.BaseObservable so we can use this ViewModel as our backing Databinding model
    // Solution came from twitter tip from Yigit Boyar and this article:
    // https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/google-i-o-2017-the-viewmodel-is-nice-from-up-here

    @Override
    public void addOnPropertyChangedCallback(Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mCallbacks == null) {
                mCallbacks = new PropertyChangeRegistry();
            }
        }
        mCallbacks.add(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mCallbacks == null) {
                return;
            }
        }
        mCallbacks.remove(callback);
    }

    /**
     * Notifies listeners that all properties of this instance have changed.
     */
    public void notifyChange() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mCallbacks == null) {
                return;
            }
        }
        mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, 0, null);
    }

    /**
     * Notifies listeners that a specific property has changed. The getter for the property
     * that changes should be marked with {@link Bindable} to generate a field in
     * <code>BR</code> to be used as <code>fieldId</code>.
     *
     * @param fieldId The generated BR id for the Bindable field.
     */
    public void notifyPropertyChanged(int fieldId) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mCallbacks == null) {
                return;
            }
        }
        mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, fieldId, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should post `OtherWorkViewModel` code to help

Comment: @MatPag Done! :-)

Comment: Trying removing the `Application` parameter inside the `OtherWorkViewModel` constructor (so end up with a default empty constructor and comment out numberFormat). I suspect the Factory is not able to init a ViewModel in this way because it doesn't know where to take the `Application` value. Try and let me know if it works, if this is the problem i will post a more detailed solution.

Comment: @MatPag I have 6 fragments/viewmodels in the app which are initialized the exactly same way. Two of them crashes the app, the rest works fine. 
So yes; I have tried this... Also I need the application object to access string resources and Local/number formatting.

Comment: Mmm ok, i think this is really hard to solve without having all the needed code in hands.. What can i suggest you is to check (if you already didn't) some of the great tips used in [this repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) provided by Google which uses dagger, to showcase arcs components. Good luck :)

Comment: @MatPag I haven't used Dagger2 before and therefore I didn't consider it for this project (there was enough to learn already... :-)  ). But I will try! Thanks for the tip and suggestions! Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make your `OtherWorkViewModel` constructor `public` and see if that helps.

Comment: Hurray! That helped! :-)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was an package class instead of public class.

Wrong:

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
```

Fixed with **public**:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
```